Insert Form Responses Value to Table In Google DOC
I'm working with Google Apps Script.
I want to make an Activity Journal Recap that is connected to

Google Form to collect data
Google Spreadsheet to accommodate data input
Google Doc to recap the Journal

What I want is the flow:

User fills in Google Form
Enter the entries into Google Spreadsheet
Incoming data is added to the table in Google Doc, with the last Form Input order being in row number 2 (after the column title).

This is my Script :
   function onFormSubmit(e) {
     var docId    = '1b9oFJmKhcFpez4yIYmrsCG6zKOZh6_b-xxxxxxx';
     var formData = e.values;

     var columnMapping = {
        1: 0,  // Try using formData[1] for the 1st column
        2: 1,  // Try using formData[2] for the 2nd column
        3: 2,  // Try using formData[3] for the 3rd column
        };

     var doc  = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
     var body = doc.getBody();

     var table   = body.getTables()[0];
     var numCols = table.getRow(0).getNumCells();

     var newRow  = table.insertTableRow(1);
        for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        newRow.insertTableCell(i, '');  // Insert blank cells
     }

    // Add data to all columns according to the mapping
     for (var sourceCol in columnMapping) {
     var targetCol = columnMapping[sourceCol];
       if (targetCol < numCols) {
     var dataToInsert = formData[sourceCol - 1];
       newRow.getCell(targetCol).setText(dataToInsert);
     }
    }
       doc.saveAndClose();
    };


Unfortunately, I was unable to retrieve the data from the spreadsheet. I can only get data from the first column in the spreadsheet to the Table in Google DOC, even though I can move to any column in the Table in Google DOC, but only one data can be retrieved.
Thank you if anyone is willing to help me.

I tested the script, added a key-value pair of 4: 3 to capture COLUMN 4 in the Google Document, and it gave me this sample output, which is what I believe you'd like to do in response to @Wicket's answer. Can you expand on I was unable to retrieve the data from the spreadsheet. I can only get data from the first column in the spreadsheet to the Table in Google DOC, even though I can move to any column in the Table in Google DOC, but only one data can be retrieved. because I'm thinking that it's the issue you're experiencing?

Below is a proposal for a function to append a row to a Google Docs table. This function call is called from a function that has got the form submitted values from a function reading the row values from the spreadsheet.
/** Add here the target document ID*/
const docId = '';

function test_appendRowContent(){
  const rowContent = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
  appendRowContent(rowContent);
}

/**
 * @param {string[]} rowContent Content of the new row to append to the first table.
 * @param {number} [tableIndex] Table index. 
 * @param {number} [rowIndex] Template row index.
 */
function appendRowContent(rowContent, tableIndex = 0, rowIndex = 0) {
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const table = body.getTables()[tableIndex];
  const templateRow = table.getChild(rowIndex);
  /**
   * Copy a row. 
   * It should have the same number of cells as the rowContent elements
   */
  const row = templateRow.asTableRow().copy();
  // Clear old content and add new content
  for(let i = 0; i < row.getNumCells(); i++){
    const cell = row.getChild(i);
    cell.setText(rowContent[i]);
  }
  // Append row to table
  table.appendTableRow(row);

}

To insert the row, you can quickly adapt the above code by replacing table.appendTableRow(row); with table.insertTableRow(1, row).
To call the above function from on function handler for a form submit trigger
function formSubmitHandler(e){
   appendRowContent(e.values);
}

Ensure the form has the same questions as the table number of columns.

Regarding the code in question, as a function called by an on-form submit trigger from a spreadsheet, the e.values already has the form-submitted data appended to the spreadsheet.
The for-in statement is a convoluted attempt to do something that could be more easily done with a for statement.
It's worth noting that the DocumentApp.Document.saveAndClose() method is not required at the end of the function, as all the changes are applied when the executions finish.

Thanks @Wicked for your proposal for my question.
But what I want is to take data from a spreadsheet (Form Responses sheet), and every time I fill out the form, the data will be added in the second row (after the column headers), while the old data will be shifted down.

You can call this function from your onFormSubmit function. If you don't know how to read data from a spreadsheet, you should ask a question about how to read the data. Be clear about how you determine which row should be copied to Google Docs or if you want to add all the rows.
